# Transform JSON to another JSON structure

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, dictionary

I have a case to transform a response from
[Dogs API](https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all)

to a different structure like this :

```
[
  {
    "breed": "pug",
    "sub_breed": []
  },
  {
    "breed": "ridgeback",
    "sub_breed": [
      {
        "breed": "rhodesian",
        "sub_breed": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "breed": "doberman",
    "sub_breed": []
  },
  {
    "breed": "hound",
    "sub_breed": [
      {
        "breed": "Ibizan",
        "sub_breed": []
      },
      {
        "breed": "afghan",
        "sub_breed": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am confused after getting the response and don't know how to transform it.

Here is what I do until getting the response

```
    public List<DogResponse> getDogs() {
        
        List<DogResponse> response = new ArrayList<DogResponse>();
        
        try {
            
            String url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all";
            
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            
            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
            
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(result.getBody().toString(), Map.class);
            
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map.get("message")));
            
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("key : "+key);
                System.out.println("val : "+value);
            }
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        
        return response;
    }
```

DogResponse

```
public class DogResponse {
    
    private String breed;
    
    private DogResponse sub_breed;

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public DogResponse getSub_breed() {
        return sub_breed;
    }

    public void setSub_breed(DogResponse sub_breed) {
        this.sub_breed = sub_breed;
    }
    
}
```

I am trying using Map but failed when I want to print the key and value, it's showing nothing.

Comment: Maybe this is a case a mapping framework like [Dozer](https://www.baeldung.com/dozer)

Comment: After reading your code, I wonder what's your DogResponse DTO for? Trying to push your response into a String map doesn't look well thaought to me. Then you could even omit RestTemplate, do a plain http request and parse the JSON on your own.

Comment: You can start with mapping the response to List<Object>. Object should be improved to another entity which contains a string and list of string

Answer (score 0):

You should map the response to List of DogResponse you may have an issue because of circular dependency.

```
List<DogResponse> dogs = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<DogResponse>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
public List<DogResponse> getDogs() {
        
       List<DogResponse> response = new ArrayList<DogResponse>();

    try {

        String url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = mapper.readValue(result.getBody().toString(), Map.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map.get("message")));
          Map<String, List<String>> innerMap = map.get("message");

          for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : innerMap.entrySet()) {
              String key = entry.getKey();
              List<String> value = entry.getValue();
              System.out.println("key : " + key);
              System.out.println("val : " + value);
          }

      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
      }
        
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, DogResponse.class);

This should work.